# Express isn't routing to static React build files because of a missing URL slug

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, amazon-eks

#### The Setup

I'm building a React app that is statically served using Express.

- The React app is built with `npm run build` and the static files live in the `build/` directory.
- Express statically serves these files with the following code ([reference](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing)):

```js
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 80;
const host = "::";

let root = path.join(__dirname, "build"); // Output of `npm run build`
app.use(express.static(root));  // Tell Express to serve static files from here

// The wildcard (*) lets all paths bypass Express 
// in favor of React handling client-side routing.
app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(root, "index.html"));
});

app.listen(port, host, () => {
  console.log(`Serving from root=${root}`);
  console.log(`Example app listening on host ${host} & port ${port}`);
});
```

I'm also containerizing the app and deploying it to EKS behind an Ingress (aka, an entrypoint).

- The Ingress URL is `ingress.company.com`
- My app has an address reserved at `ingress.company.com/my-app`. All users must be able to go here, so every URL should use this `/my-app` slug.

#### The Problem

When I point my browser to `ingress.company.com/my-app`, Express successfully returns `build/index.html`. However, the accompanying static JavaScript files aren't being found resulting in a bare HTML file without life.

I've discovered the reason why:

- The static JavaScript file lives at `ingress.company.com/my-app/js/main.hash.js`
- Express is trying to reach files at `ingress.company.com/js/main.hash.js` (missing `my-app/`) and a 404 is returned.

How can I get my Static Express Server to include the URL slug `my-app/` when serving for build files? Is there a way to set a Base URL?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official Create React App docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths):

> By default, Create React App produces a build assuming your app is hosted at the server root.
> To override this, specify the homepage in your package.json, for example:

```json
  "homepage": "http://mywebsite.com/relativepath",
```

> This will let Create React App correctly infer the root path to use in the generated HTML file.